# How to align a footer without it being overlap other contents when resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple landing page. I went for minimalistic look and made a simple land page. But while trying to add a footer, it **overlaps my content** that I have aligned to center. I made an exactly same code on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/athul_p/pen/xxdKgNP) please view it there or use the code provided below.

My HTML:

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Some Header</h1>
      <div class="main-land-container">
             
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli</p>
        <input placeholder="Lorem"></input>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="submit"> </input>
        <input type="date"></input>

    </div>
  <footer>
    <h3>Some sample footer</h3>
  </footer>
  </body>
```

My css:

```css
body {
  background-color: #24292e;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
  color: white;
}
p {
  color: yellow;
}

input {
margin: 2em;
}

/*-------Below is the code that causes the problem*/

.main-land-container {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* For card */
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute; /*For centering */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  text-align: center;
}

.main-land-container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-land-items {
  margin: 2em;
}


footer {
  background-color: red; /*For debugging*/
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/*I can edit the footer and the main-land-container as long as it looks like what it is now. All I want is my footer to stay at bottom without overlapping my content in the card.*/
```

It works very nice on laptops or dekstop. But if I open it on my phone, or resize it, or opened a keyboard to type on my phone, the footer is dragged up and overlaps my content.

Heres a preview of desktop:
[image: Desktop]

Heres if I scaled my device to mobile:
[image: Mobile devices]

The thing is, the card cant be even scrolled to the bottom if I use mobile. The footer overlaps the card.

Thank you for helping. Please comment if any more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you must remove position fixed (and other rules related to position) for footer. That rule will be look just simpler:

```
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Then use follow code for body:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Another way: just add to div `.main-land-container` property margin-bottom with value equal to footer height in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I think your content is less, which is not scrollable due to fixed footer, so you must remove fixed footer